# Arabic Stemming on XML file in python?

Tags: python, xml-parsing, nlp, arabic, elementtree

I have an Arabic XML below is a small sample. I want to stem all the XML except those in `<en>` tags, and I want the words to change in the original XML file.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<TEXT>
<PHRASE>
<PSEUDO-V>ان</PSEUDO-V>
<N>وزير</N>
<N>الخارجية</N>
<en x='PERS'>فرانك فالتر شتاينماير</en>
<V y='0'>سيتوجه</V>
<N>السبت</N>
<PREP>إلى</PREP>
<en x='LOC'>الشرق الأوسط</en>
</PHRASE>
<PHRASE>
<V>علم</V>
<N>الأهل</N>
<PREP>ب</PREP>
<N y='1'>مغادرت</N>
<en x='PERS'>البابا</en>
<PREP y='1'>إلى</PREP>
<en x='LOC'>المدينة مكة</en>
</PHRASE>
<PHRASE> 
</TEXT>
```

I tried the following but for some reason it didn't work.
**note:** X attribute in `<en>` tag is either: LOC-PERS-DATE-ORG

```
import re
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from nltk.stem.isri import ISRIStemmer

tree2 = ET.parse('TrainBaseEnglishcopy.xml')
root2 = tree2.getroot()


for phrase in root2.findall('./PHRASE'):
    ens = {en.get('x'): en.text for en in phrase.findall('en')}
    if not ('ORG' in ens and 'PERS' in ens and 'LOC' in ens and 'DATE' in ens):
      phrase=st.stem(phrase)
```

I got the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "20Dec.py", line 475, 
     in <module> phrase=st.stem(phrase) 
File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/n‌​ltk/stem/isri.py", line 153, 
     in stem token = self.norm(token, 1) # remove diacritics which representing Arabic short vowels 
File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/n‌​ltk/stem/isri.py", line 186, 
     in norm word = self.re_short_vowels.sub('', word) TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object –
```

Note: Stemming on its own is working fine
for example

```
w = 'يعمل'
print (st.stem(w))
```

works fine.

---Update--
**I got to work like that, but I will have to repeat for every tag, but it didn't change the text in the original XML file, any ideas ?**

```
for phrase in root2.findall('./PHRASE/N'):
    ens = {en.get('x'): en.text for en in phrase.findall('en')}
    if not ('ORG' in ens and 'PERS' in ens and 'LOC' in ens and 'DATE' in ens):
      phrase.text=st.stem(phrase.text)
      print(phrase.text)
```

Comment: what;s the error that you get?

Comment: Hi - you can't stem `phrase` because it is an ElementTree Element, not a string. You have to find the subelements of phrase and then stem their .text, which _is_ a string. Try adding a `print phrase` and you'll see that it prints information about an Element object.

Comment: Did you write the modified xml out to an xml file? Look at this in the python docs, shows you how to modify an xml file. https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#modifying-an-xml-file

Comment: I upvoted you for having a much better question this time, because you included what looks like complete executable code showing your problem - but don't forget you can edit the question to show your latest code - e.g. add a line UPDATE and below it paste what you are trying now rather than deleting the original, so it is obvious where you started and what you are trying now.

Comment: @I.Abdelsalam: *"below is a small sample"*. With your latest edit, you removed the sample and all code. Why did you do that? Now the question is much worse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your XML file modified, you should commit it using the command `tree.write` at the end:

```
tree2 = ET.parse('TrainBaseEnglishcopy.xml')
root2 = tree2.getroot()

# ...manipulate tree...

tree2.write("out.xml", encoding="UTF-8")
```

Comment: I tried that but I can't really tell if it worked since the output is in unicode, can I make the output it arabic as the original XML file.
<TEXT>
<PHRASE>
<CONJ>&#1608;</CONJ>
<V>&#1580;&#1575;&#1569;&#1578;</V>
<N updates="yes">&#1589;&#1585;&#1581;</N>
<N updates="yes">&#1608;&#1586;&#1585;</N>
<ADJ>&#1575;&#1604;&#1571;&#1605;&#1610;&#1585;&#1603;&#1610;&#1577;</ADJ>
<ADV>&#1576;&#1593;&#1583;</ADV>
<N updates="yes" y="0">&#1593;&#1608;&#1583;</N>
<en x="PERS">&#1607;&#1575;</en>
<PREP>&#1605;&#1606;</PREP>
<en x="LOC">&#1606;&#1610;&#1608;&#1610;&#1608;&#1585;&#1603;</en>
</PHRASE>

Comment: try: `tree2.write("out.xml", encoding="UTF-8")`